# Это общая переменная для всех пользователей?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

в node.js express есть req.app.set и res.app.get. Я разрабатываю сайт и в зависимости от действий пользователя создаться переменная через req.app.set, потом считывается через res.app.get. Все вроде хорошо работало и я решил для теста выложить сайт на heroku. Но когда я заполняю эту переменную на одном устройстве она заполняется на другом и наоборот, т.е они связанные. Это особенность heroku или приведенных выше методов? Это будет также на нормальном платном хостинге? Если это особенность методов то можно просто создать переменную через let или const или она тоже будет доступная всем пользователям? Если да то как решить эту проблему? Я новичок и это мой первый вопрос поэтому если что-то сделал не так извиняюсь.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Покажите код. Но вообще-то да, req.app это общий объект для всех запросов. Вам нужен res.locals или даже просто хранить данные прямо в объекте req (хотя это может быть опасно, тем и так много полей)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Спасибо за ответ